# If URL query string value is false display error message on next page using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have login page and admin page on admin page it check if username and password are correct If correct go to login page else not!
so on admin page I have a link for login page in that url I gave query string with message= error;
and on Login page i want to test :
so how to do this please help!!

```html
<?php
use Ct\Ct\Data\Data;
  if ($username == $accounts[0]->user_name && $password == $accounts[0]->user_pass) {
       
    }
 else{
  print('<script>window.location.href="https://ct.org/login-gun-page-updates/?message=error"</script>'); 
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>update page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="" method="POST">
 <label class="update_heading"> UPDATE GUN DRAWING TICKETS </label> <a href='https://ct.org/logout-gunpage-update-form/' class="logout_link" > Logout</a><br>
  <label for="update" class="update"> Update Number: </label><input type="textbox" id="ticketsavailable" name="ticketsavailable" value="<?php echo $ticketleft[0]->ticket_available; ?>"/><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit">
</form>
 
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
if(message ==  error){
echo 'Invalid username or password, please check again!';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
        <title>Login Gun Page Update</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="login" id="login" method="POST" action="https://ct.org/admin-gunpage-update/">
            <label class="log_in"> LOGIN </label>
            <p><label for="username" class="username">Username: </label><input type="text" size="100" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="UserName"/></p>
            <p><label for="password" class="password">Password: </label><input type="password" size="40" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password"/></p>
            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Submit"/> <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" class="reset" value="reset"/></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? "How to do this" is a bit broad...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In PHP GET requests are handled by `$_GET['your_arguement_name']`.

Your redirection should look like:

```
print('<script>window.location.href="https://ct.org/login-gun-page-updates/?message=error"</script>');

// If your message value is a PHP variable.
$message = "error";
print('<script>window.location.href="https://ct.org/login-gun-page-updates/?message='.$message.'"</script>');
```

And the php that handles `message` argument will look like:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['message']) && !empty($_GET['message']) &&  $_GET['message'] == 'error'){
        echo 'Invalid username or password, please check again!';
    }
    // Upon Ivan suggestion you can also do (both will work though)  
    if(!empty($_GET['message']) &&  $_GET['message'] == 'error'){
        echo 'Invalid username or password, please check again!';
    }
?>
```

> **[isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)** : Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.
>
> **[empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)** : Determine whether a variable is empty.

Comment: "_in that url I gave query string with message= error_" It's `$_GET` though

Comment: that means I have to write window.location.href="https://ct.org/login-gun-page-updates/?$_GET['message']=error";

Comment: @BindiyaRose No, your redirecting URL is correct. Check my updated answer.

Comment: problem is how to pass PHP code in script tag    print('<script>window.location.href="https://ct.org/login-gun-page-updates/?$_GET['message']=error"</script>');

Comment: @BindiyaRose You cannot pass PHP code in the query string. You can only pass variale names and their corresponding values. You are doing it correctly. If it doesn't work for you, you might have to adjust your .htaccess file to let the query string through.

Comment: @BindiyaRose Check my improved answer for passing php variable in JS

Comment: thank you Its working but its bydefault showing on login page invalid username and password!! still user have not entered any username and password ...so?? for this??

Comment: Did you put the `isset()` and `!empty()` clause as showed in my answer ? That's is to prevent that by default error

Comment: @DaniyalNasir there is no need for that. Not only that, but your example has errors. What is this: `!empty(isset($_GET['message']))` ? This makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Ivan86 That's a mistake but it won't create any error.

Comment: @BindiyaRose as Ivan mentioned, kindly replace `!empty(isset($_GET['message']))` with `!empty($_GET['message'])`

Comment: @DaniyalNasir There is no need to check `issset()` and `!empty()`. Only `!empty` will do. _**empty():** determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist._

Comment: Happy to help @BindiyaRose . Kindly accept it as your answer.

Comment: one more question if i pass query string in header will it work??header('location: http://localhost:82/?page_id=1865?message=error');

Comment: @BindiyaRose yes, it will work. Just write `header('location: example.php?page_id=1865&message=error'); exit();`. If you put `exit();` right after `header()` no other code will execute and the page will redirect immediately.

Comment: @BindiyaRose If you are redirecting with a `<script>` then you need to put the script inside the `<head>` or `<body>` of the HTML document. If you use `header()` then you should put it above the `<!DOCTYPE html ...` because the `header()` won't work if there is any output before it.

Comment: @BindiyaRose If you want to redirect and send data to the **same** (current) page use this: `header('location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page_id=1865&message=error'); exit();`

Comment: Yes, it should work just fine after full filling the requirements @Ivan86 just mentioned.

Comment: thank you, could you please help with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563374/updated-text-is-not-getting-updated-on-wordpress-page-immediately-every-time-it

Comment: @BindiyaRose I'll take a look at it. Will you please accept this one as answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **`$_GET[]`** global array to extract the `message` from the query string.

This would be your **login PHP page:**

```
<?php
    // check if variable message exists, is not empty, and equal to 'error'
    if(!empty($_GET['message']) && $_GET['message'] ==  'error')
    {
        echo 'Invalid username or password, please check again!';
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login Gun Page Update</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="login" id="login" method="POST" action="https://ct.org/admin-gunpage-update/">
        <label class="log_in"> LOGIN </label>
        <p><label for="username" class="username">Username: </label><input type="text" size="100" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="UserName"/></p>
        <p><label for="password" class="password">Password: </label><input type="password" size="40" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password"/></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Submit"/> <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" class="reset" value="reset"/></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In your admin PHP file, use **`echo`** to print out the `<script>`, and also move your `<script>` to the `<head>` or `<body>` of the document. This would be your **admin PHP file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>update page</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    use Cct\CharlesGoodNight\Data\Data;
    if ($username == $accounts[0]->user_name && $password == $accounts[0]->user_pass)
    {
       echo 'Correct username and password';
    }
    else
    {
       echo '<script>window.location.href="https://ct.org/login-gun-page-updates/?message=error"</script>'; 
    }
?>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <label class="update_heading"> UPDATE GUN DRAWING TICKETS </label>
    <a href='https://ct.org/logout-gunpage-update-form/' class="logout_link" > Logout</a><br>
    <label for="update" class="update"> Update Number: </label>
    <input type="textbox" id="ticketsavailable" name="ticketsavailable" value="<?php echo $ticketleft[0]->ticket_available; ?>"/>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit">
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you yourself my friend got a typo `i!empty($_GET['message'])` . You're welcome